# Reliable Message Delivery

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Sorry I need to explain a bit before to get to the issue.

I am using Kafka Client 0.9.0.0 to send messages to Kafka cluster. The system is sort of a pipeline, which consumes messages from JMS and sends it to Kafka. To ensure message reliability, JMS acknowledge mode is set to CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE, so that when the message is consumed and processed successfully, the application acknowledge the message receipt.

Once the message is consumed, the message is send to Kafka and this is where the issue is.

**Asynchronous:**

I can use Kafka producer async send with with callback, and if there is an error sending the message to Kafka, it will be too late to inform the JMS consumer not to acknowledge the message consumption. To overcome this, the only thing that I came up with is to perist the messages in Callback if there is an exception, and try send the messages later. But I think that will be too much of overhead.

Is there any other way to deal with this situation using asynchronous call ?

**Synchronous:**

Using the synchronous call, calling get() on the future returned by Producer.send(), exception will be thrown if there is any issue while sending message to Kafka and it can be reported back to JMS consumer so that it won't acknowledge the message and retry it at later point.

Obviously it will have performance impact, since this will be a blocking call and the bad part is there will be no batching of messages since Kafka will acknowledge each message.

I am inclining towards synchronous call, because I don't want additional persistence.

Is there any way or configuration, where I can use synchronous call and also minimize the impact from synchronous calls ? One configuration that I made is to have a pool of JMS consumers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Asynchronous way:**

There is no other way than to persist. You have a trade off for performance.

You have received a message from JMS. Acknowledged that you read it. When trying to push to a topic in kafka, for some reason it failed. You need to do two things for this to be reliable.

1. Have a redelivery mechanism to push to kafka if it failed. You can have an exponential back off retry mechanism which will cater to intermittent issues (For example, network outages)
2. Create an error topic in kafka or JMS to which you send the messages if the kafka push failed. Have the error topic again as an input to your pipeline. You will need to throttle the consumption from error topic as it may overload you application if due to some reason, the push is failing repeatedly.

This will make it much reliable.

**Synchronous way:**

I am not sure how you can improve the performance in this case. If performance is not an issue in your application, I suggest you go this way since this is the fastest and easiest approach.

I am not sure what you meant by persisting in callback. If you meant that you will be storing messages in memory, that is a bad idea as you will lose messages if the app is shutdown or stopped for some reason.

Comment: By persisting in callback, I meant storing the message to some persistent store like database or other kafka topic like you said.

Comment: For the async way, it is important to note that the sequence of messages will no longer be guaranteed.